# Preserve special characters and null while using spark dataframe csv write

Tags: null, character

I have data like below with NUL and special characters
ABCDEF|  ABC
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoBNB.png)

When I try to write this using csv, it prints out additional NUL characters that weren't part of data. I want to preseve the special characters. Here's the write statement and output. Basically, i want to change the delimiter to 3 character , and then write it to disk.

df.write.options(header="false",delimiter=',,,').mode("overwrite").csv("outputfile",quote="",encoding='ISO-8859-1',nullValue="NULL",escape="")
ABCDEF|   ABC
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfj5Z.png)

This is what I have, would love to hear suggestions to improve handling special characters using csv.